# Optimize HTML5 video for Retina displays?

Tags: html, video, retina-display

I'd like to provide a low-res and a high-res version of a video, the latter one is intended for retina displays. This video should be embedded in a html5 page. In particular this will be an iPad web app.

Is there an easy way to let the browser engine choose the correct one (e.g. from multiple `<source>` tags) or do I have to do some JS-foo? I did find a lot of solutions for `<img>`, `<canvas>` and CSS handling, but no best practice for videos.

Comment: Good question. For images, some people just provide the retina image to everyone, because you can sometimes use more aggressive JPG compression on retina images without losing visible quality (see http://blog.netvlies.nl/design-interactie/retina-revolution/, but also http://silev.org/test/Retina-resize.html). I'm not sure if a similar trick could work for video; I guess it would depend on the codec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could try and use the [media attribute](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/08/html5/responsive-html5-video) on `source` elements.

A code example is given below:

```
<video controls> 
   <source src="video-small.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (max-width:480px)"> 
   <source src="video-small.webm" type="video/webm" media="all and (max-width:480px)"> 
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
   <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm"> 
</video>
```

The issue is finding a media query that would help indicate that the display is retina.

**EDIT**
I tested this a bit more, and it turns out that you also need to set a media query on the other sources as they seem to take priority. I wrote a bit about it at: [HTML5 video for retina displays](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/12/html5/html5-video-for-retina-displays).

Comment: "The issue is finding a media query that would help indicate that the display is retina." - That would be [`min-device-pixel-ratio`](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/), or at least its prefixed versions.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I wasn't aware of that. I wonder what browser support is like?

Comment: Funny you should ask! [Safari 3+, Chrome 1+](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%40media_%28-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio%29), [Firefox 4+](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%40media_%28min--moz-device-pixel-ratio%29), [Opera 11.1+](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%40media_%28-o-min-device-pixel-ratio%29). (I really must get that site up-to-date.)

Comment: I must also get devices in there.

Comment: Great, thanks! Especially for the article you wrote that explains the need of media queries in every source tag, which I suppose a lot of people would have gone through by themselves. :)

Comment: You are not allowed to use `media` attribute if the parent is `<video>`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source#:~:text=2x%20for%20example).-,media,-Allowed%20if%20the

Comment: @LevonGrigoryan My answer is from 2012, which you can clearly see, and at that time you could.

Comment: @IanDevlin, sure, I can see that. I just wanted to shout that the answer is not relevant anymore.